# Adding homebrew to $PATH without sudo privileges

Tags: path, homebrew, macos-mojave

I've been trying to install homebrew without admin privileges on my school MacBook (Mojave 10.14.6) for the past 2 weeks. I've seen many things on the internet, saw some scripts, tutorials, but nothing seems to help.

I used this script (did some tweaking to it like changing to a new repository and setting absolute path)

`https://gist.github.com/skyl/36563a5be809e54dc139`

the repository I used is

`https://github.com/Homebrew/brew`

my path to `brew` is

`/Users/as.gurban-zade/Desktop/homebrew/usr/local/bin/brew`

I added this to the $PATH using

`echo "export PATH=/Users/as.gurban-zade/Desktop/homebrew/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`

also tried

`echo "export PATH=/Users/as.gurban-zade/Desktop/homebrew/usr/local/:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`

After everything I did, I still get

`-bash: brew: command not found`

Updating OS to Catalina is possible if that would help

Comment: Did you use  `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` to install?

Comment: oh, yeah, i've did it some other way by copying it and creating it on the desktop. the one script you give me still asks for sudo privileges